# AsyncTask waiting on other AsyncTasks

Tags: java, android, concurrency, android-asynctask

I have built multiple asynctasks to handle multiple different tasks. The primary objective is to 'reset data' which will involve:

1. Deleting all existing data in database, table x
2. Deleting all existing local files related to data
3. Submit web-request to download JSON that will provide 'refreshed' data
4. Parse JSON
5. Store JSON in database
6. Download new local files based on JSON data (i.e. will include image URLs)
7. Store downloaded files

Today, I have 'achieved' this with a main AsyncTask that creates multiple 'sub'-AsyncTasks to get the job done. Code for this task below:

```
private class GetMetaDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private List<MatchDetail> results;
    private long accountId;

    public GetMetaDataTask(Context c) {     
        this.context = c;
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.setMessage("Downloading JSON...");
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... inputs) {     
            /** Items **/
            List <Item> items = stats.getItemsMeta();
            List <MetaImageDownloader> metaDownloaders = new ArrayList<MetaImageDownloader>();
            if (items.size() > 0) {
                new ResourceHelper(null, context).deleteLocalImages(ResourceHelper.PATH_ITEMS);
                db.deleteItems();
                for (Item i: items) {           
                    //Store in database
                    db.storeItem(i);
                    //Download images
                    new MetaImageDownloader(context, i.getItemImg(),MetaImageDownloader.JOB_DOWNLOAD_ITEM)).execute();
                }

            }
        return null;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

         db.close();
            if (dialog != null) 
                dialog.dismiss();
     }
}
```

And below is the doInBackground code for MetaImageDownloader:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... imgTypes) {
    ResourceHelper rh = new ResourceHelper(null, context);
    if (jobType == JOB_DOWNLOAD_ITEM) { 
        bmp = rh.getBitmapFromURL(getItemImageUrl(downloadCode));
        rh.saveImageLocally(bmp, ResourceHelper.PATH_ITEMS, downloadCode);
        if (bmp != null)
            bmp.recycle();

    } 
    ...
```

To break it down,

**1) Delete all existing data:**

`db.deleteItems();`

**2) Delete all existing local files related to data:**

`new ResourceHelper(null, context).deleteLocalImages(ResourceHelper.PATH_ITEMS);`

**3/4) Submit web-request to download JSON that will provide 'refreshed' data & Parse:**

`List <Item> items = stats.getItemsMeta();`

**5) Store JSON in database:**
`db.storeItem(i);`

**6) Download new local files based on JSON data:**

`new MetaImageDownloader(context, i.getItemImg(),MetaImageDownloader.JOB_DOWNLOAD_ITEM)).execute();`

(Inside MetaImageDownloader) - `bmp = rh.getBitmapFromURL(getItemImageUrl(downloadCode));`

**7) Store downloaded files:**

(Inside MetaImageDownloader) - `rh.saveImageLocally(bmp, ResourceHelper.PATH_ITEMS, downloadCode);`

--

Whew! Now, #6 is a new AsyncTask being run per Item to concurrently download all images at once. The challenge I am having is being able to determine when all **MetaImageDownloader** AsyncTasks have completed. I can get onPostExecute per image downloaded, but not when all 161 have been completed.

Question 1 - Am I breaking standards by creating AsyncTasks from within an AsyncTask? I know that the biggest issue is being unable to update UI from these 'sub-AsyncTasks'

Question 2 - How do I notify UI when all 161 MetaImageDownloader AsyncTasks have completed?

**UPDATE:** I created a new function to perform #6/7:

```
public void batchDownloadSaveImages(List<Item> items, List<Hero> heroes, String heroImgTypes[]) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
List<Runnable> requests = new ArrayList<Runnable>();

    final ExecutorService pool = Executors
            .newFixedThreadPool(Const.MAX_THREAD_POOL);
    int reqCounter = 1;

    for (final Item item : items) {
        requests.add(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {     
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmapFromURL(getItemImageUrl(item.getItemImg()));
                saveImageLocally(bmp, ResourceHelper.PATH_HEROES, item.getItemImg());
            }
        });
        reqCounter++;
    }

    List<Future> runnables = new ArrayList<Future>();

    for (Runnable request : requests) {
        runnables.add(pool.submit(request));
    }

    for (Future future : runnables) {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("- Received request. " + --reqCounter
                    + " requests to go!");
        }
    }

    // Wait till everything has calmed down!
    pool.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A standard pattern for what you are trying to achieve goes like this:

```
function on_all_tasks_done() {
  // do something
}

tasks = generate_async_taks()
var nb_tasks = tasks.size()
var callback = function() {
  nb_tasks--
  if (nb_tasks == 0) on_all_tasks_done();
};

for (var i = 0; i < nb_tasks; i++) {
  var task = tasks[i]
  task.execute_then_invoke(callback)
}
```

Expanding on the large comments portion:
This question started out as: If I have a set of tasks and run them asynchronously, how can I react to the 'all_tasks_done' event. I answered this question. And now you are basically asking stuff, like:

'How should I structure my code?' or 'What is the best strategy to write maintainable asynchronous code?'

Such questions are non-trivial to answer and more over you kind of lack the necessary terminology. I'm afraid there's only so much I can do :)

Comment: If I did this on main thread wouldn't this lock up UI defeating the purpose of using Asynctasks?

Comment: You can decrement nb_tasks from the thread of your choice. Depending on what you want to do, you may need to execute 'on_all_tasks_done' on the UI thread. For example, if this method should show provide UI feedback, explaining that the job is done. All in all I generally try to avoid nested tasks. It makes stuff complicated and most often does not speed up you code either.

Comment: Consider this: If you create 100 Tasks that should load additional resources and perform some local computation and you want to react to the 'all_tasks_done' event: Now if all tasks load images from a Webserver then those requests will be syncronized either way, because the Webserver can only process one request (or O(1)) at a time.

Comment: I think it would be best, if you created an ExecutorServices (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Say one for images, one for texts, and one for

Comment: Following Recommendation (your numbers above): 
1. do it syncronously (it won't take long)
2. either do it sync, or provide a callback (you really want to avoid filename collisions)
3/4/5. perform your request and receive JSON using AsyncTask a Thread or whatever and store it in the db. (you use a thread here sot the UI does not block)

Comment: 6/7. Create an Executor that can execute a number (say 5 or maybe 10) Threads at a time: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int) and using this load the resources and subsequently store them. So a Thread is done here, if it has downloaded and stored it's resource. AND decremented the Thread counter (as indicted in my answer)
8. If Thread counter == 0 do something on the UI Thread

Comment: I did this with Runnables and noted it was much more efficient when I use a thread pool of 25). Have updated my question with this. What do you think of how I have implemented this?

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily complicated, consider writing: 
ReqCounte myreqCounter = new ReqCounter(items.size());
for (Item item : items) {
  pool.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // do stuff
      myreqcounter.decrement();
      if (myreqcounter.isZero()) {
      // all tasks done
      }
    }
  });
}

Comment: I also noticed, that you don't really understand what 'synchronized' does and what an 'Executioner' does. Unfortunately concurrency in Java is not exactly simple to explain. May I refer you to this explanation: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Comment: There is no need to create an Executor!  AsyncTasks are, exactly, run on an Executor.  They are run serially, if you use execute(), but you can run several at a time by using executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR).   If you want an application that actually works, however, you will move all this stuff out of AsyncTasks and into a Service.